# Search a ListBox and Select result in C#

Tags: c#, search, listbox

I have searched the site but could not find a answer.

I have a listbox called "CompetitorDetailsOutput" I then have a textbox above called "searchbox" and a button called "searchbutton" The data in the list box constanly changes and get it data from a .txt file wich stores the  data in the following format

```
string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12}", Name, CPSA, PostCode, Rank, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Score6, Score7, Score8, TotalSingleScore);
```

the listbox then displays as follows

```
string.Format("{0,-20}|{1,-10}|{2,-9}|{3,-7}|{4,2}|{5,2}|{6,2}|{7,2}|{8,2}|{9,2}|{10,2}|{11,2}|{12,3}", Name, CPSA, PostCode, Rank, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Score6, Score7, Score8, TotalSingleScore)
```

I want to be able to search the listbox as follows:
user only enters data into "searchbox" and presses "searchbutton", system then searches the listbox, If it finds it selects the item in the listbox, if not then a close match is selected, if there are no close matches then a error message is displayed.

**Code is C# and software VS 2008 Pro**

Thanks

Comment: hi. I have no code for the search function, i did try a few if statments with some other things but had no luck :( but i can show you how the listbox is populated if that helps? By a close match i mean something like spaces ignored so user search is "hello world", there is no "hello world" but there is "helloworld" so maybe something like search for "hello world" then search for "helloworld" if a record with the space is not found.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this to get your 'match' algorithm started:

```
foreach (var item in ListBox.Items)
{
    if (item.Text.Contains(searchArg))
    {
        //select this item in the ListBox.
        ListBox.SelectedValue = item.Value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I have a SQL query which has data and if the data matches the ListBox then auto-select it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034566/how-to-auto-select-listbox-items-from-a-dropdownlist/31034726?noredirect=1#comment50093972_31034726

Answer (score 1):

1./ Create an object with the properties that you want to search
    on
    2./ Add your items as an object rather than as a string
    3./ override the ToString() with the format that you want to display in
    the listbox
    4./ Use Linq to query your objects as you like.

```
var result = from o in ListBox.Items.OfType<yourClass>()
             where o.Whatever == yourCriteria
             select o;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void FindAllOfMyString(string searchString)
    {
        // Set the SelectionMode property of the ListBox to select multiple items.
        ListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

        // Set our intial index variable to -1.
        int x = -1;
        // If the search string is empty exit.
        if (searchString.Length != 0)
        {
            // Loop through and find each item that matches the search string.
            do
            {
                // Retrieve the item based on the previous index found. Starts with -1 which searches start.
                x = ListBox.FindString(searchString, x);
                // If no item is found that matches exit.
                if (x != -1)
                {
                    // Since the FindString loops infinitely, determine if we found first item again and exit.
                    if (ListBox.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (x == ListBox.SelectedIndices[0])
                            return;
                    }
                    // Select the item in the ListBox once it is found.
                    ListBox.SetSelected(x, true);
                }
            } while (x != -1);
        }
    }

private void Srchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FindAllOfMyString(SrchBox.Text);
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.findstring(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: *Comment by anonymous user:* I added `break;` right after the `listbox.setselected` line because the code gets stuck in a loop. Adding `break;` solves this. Also if you want the `listbox` to be single select then add `ListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;` to the `listbox` click event. Bye :)