# Search listbox for item containing a string

Tags: c#, search, listbox

**Background**: I am building a database application to store information about my massive movie collection. The listbox contains hundreds of items so I decided to implement a search feature which would highlight all items that contain a particular string. Sometimes it's hard to remember an entire movie title so I thought this would come in handy.

I found this useful code on the Microsoft site that highlights all items in a listbox that contain a particular string. How can I modify it to search through each string entirely?

Currently the code only searches for items that **start** with the search string, instead of seeing if it contains the search string anywhere else. I came across a listbox.items.contains() kind of method on Google, although I have no idea how to convert my code for it.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1094277.aspx/1

```
private void FindAllOfMyString(string searchString)
{
   // Set the SelectionMode property of the ListBox to select multiple items.
   listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

   // Set our intial index variable to -1.
   int x =-1;
   // If the search string is empty exit.
   if (searchString.Length != 0)
   {
      // Loop through and find each item that matches the search string.
      do
      {
         // Retrieve the item based on the previous index found. Starts with -1 which searches start.
         x = listBox1.FindString(searchString, x);
         // If no item is found that matches exit.
         if (x != -1)
         {
            // Since the FindString loops infinitely, determine if we found first item again and exit.
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
            {
               if(x == listBox1.SelectedIndices[0])
                  return;
            }
            // Select the item in the ListBox once it is found.
            listBox1.SetSelected(x,true);
         }

      }while(x != -1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create your own search function, something along the lines of

```
int FindMyStringInList(ListBox lb,string searchString,int startIndex)
{
     for(int i=startIndex;i<lb.Items.Count;++i)
     {
         string lbString = lb.Items[i].ToString();
         if(lbString.Contains(searchString))
            return i;
     }
     return -1;
}
```

(beware, I wrote this out of my head without compiling or testing, the code may contain bugs, but I think you will get the idea!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) for a case-insenstive string search on each item in your ListBox:

```
private void FindAllOfMyString(string searchString) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
        if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) {
            listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
        } else {
            // Do this if you want to select in the ListBox only the results of the latest search.
            listBox1.SetSelected(i, false);
        }
    }
}
```

I also suggest they you set your ListBox's SelectionMode property in the Winform designer, or in your forms constructor method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the code you posted, but I wrote a small method to do what you're looking for. It's extremely simple:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
        IEnumerable items = listBox1.Items;
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            string movieName = item as string;

            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieName)) && movieName.Contains(searchString))
            {
                indices.Add(listBox1.Items.IndexOf(item));
            }
        }
        indices.ForEach(index => listBox1.SelectedIndices.Add(index));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the below. You just need to improve it a bit

```
   using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Item
    {
        public Item(string id,string desc)
        {
            id = id;
            Desc = desc;
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public const string Searchtext="o";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        }

        public static List<Item> GetItems()
        {
            return new List<Item>()
                       {
                           new Item("1","One"),
                           new Item("2","Two"),
                           new Item("3","Three"),
                           new Item("4","Four")
                       };
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.DataSource = GetItems();
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Desc";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
            listBox1.ClearSelected();
            listBox1.Items.Cast<Item>()
                .ToList()
                .Where(x => x.Desc.Contains("o")).ToList()
                .ForEach(x => listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.FindString(x.Desc),true));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same question was asked:
[Search a ListBox and Select result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610108/search-a-listbox-and-select-result-in-c)

I propose another solution:

1. Not good for listbox > 1000 items.
2. Each iteration loops all items.
3. Finds and stays on most suitable case.

   ```
    
       // Save last successful match.
       private int lastMatch = 0;
       // textBoxSearch - where the user inputs his search text
       // listBoxSelect - where we searching for text
       private void textBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           // Index variable.
           int x = 0;
           // Find string or part of it.
           string match = textBoxSearch.Text;
           // Examine text box length 
           if (textBoxSearch.Text.Length != 0)
           {
               bool found = true;
               while (found)
               {
                   if (listBoxSelect.Items.Count == x)
                   {
                       listBoxSelect.SetSelected(lastMatch, true);
                       found = false;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       listBoxSelect.SetSelected(x, true);
                       match = listBoxSelect.SelectedValue.ToString();
                       if (match.Contains(textBoxSearch.Text))
                       {
                           lastMatch = x;
                           found = false;
                       }
                       x++;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Hope this help!

Answer (score -2):

just one liner

```
 if(LISTBOX.Items.Contains(LISTBOX.Items.FindByText("anystring")))
//string found
else
//string not found
```

:) Regards