# How to search a listbox via a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried to search the listbox but its only searching the first column, the other columns its like there are not there. The data in the listbox is separated by space its a 4 column data.

This is what I have tried

```
listBox1.ClearSelected();
string data = txtSearch.Text;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
{
    int index = listBox1.FindString(data);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        listBox1.SetSelected(index, false);
        MessageBox.Show("string" + data + "found at index " + index);
        txtSearch.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Search string did not match any item");
        txtSearch.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: A ListBox does not contain multiple columns, and the `FindString` method only finds entires that start with the search data. You may need to use `FindStringExact`, or write your own search method

Comment: For those of you who think a ListBox does not contain multiple columns, [here is the documentation on how to enable and use multiple columns in a ListBox.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267368/search-listbox-for-item-containing-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write how you filled your ListBox. Usually there are two ways to fill a Listbox:

- Do it directly using property [ListBox.Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.items?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)
- Use the more generic method: [ListControl.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)

You didn't say what kind of things you are displaying, let's assume you display some properties of a Product: Id, Name, Price. You want to display them in neat columns in your ListBox.

```
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}
```

Somewhere you have a method that fetches the Products that you want to display in the Listbox:

```
IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsToDisplay() {...}
```

### Solution if you used DataSource

Whenever you want to display sequences of items in a winforms control, this is the preferred method, because using this method, you won't think in displayed descriptions of a product, but in an object of `DisplayedProduct`. It the operator selects a string in the ListBox, internally he selects a Product. It is way easier for software to determine which product is selected.

Besides that it is easier to access the Product, using the DataSource decouples the displayed items from the control that is used to display it. If later you decide that you want to display your sequence of Products in a DataGridView, changes are minimal. You can even reuse the classes if you want to display (the prices of) the Products in a more excotic control like a Graph.

```
class DisplayedProduct
{
    // ths format string to convert the Product into its displayformat
    private const string descriptionFormat = ...;

    public Product Product {get; set;}

    public string Description => String.Format(descriptionFormat,
        this.Product.Id,
        this.Product.Name,
        this.Product.Price);
}
```

In the constructor of your form, you use property [ListControl.DisplayMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) to define which property is used to display:

```
void MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.myListbox.DisplayMember = nameof(DisplayedProduct.Description);
}
```

You can also use visual studio designer to do this, but this method has the advantage that your compiler will complain if you have a typing error.

Now to display the products:

```
IEnumerable<Product> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => this.myListBox.DataSource
        .Select(displayedProduct => displayedProduct.Product);
    set => this.myListBox.DataSource = value
        .Select(product => new DisplayedProduct {Product = product))
        .ToList();
}
```

So to display your Products, you offer a sequence of Products, the set property will convert this into a `list<DisplayedProducts>`, and puts the result in the DataSource of the ListBox.

To fetch the DisplayedProducts, the `list<DisplayedProducts>` is fetched from the DataSource. From each element in this list, property Product is fetched.

Displaying your Products is a one liner:

```
this.DisplayedProducts = this.GetProductsToDisplay();
```

Once you've created method DisplayedProducts, it is easy to search for a Product with a specific text in its Name:

```
const string textToSearch = "Hammer"

// find all Hammers:
IEnumerable<Product> hammers = this.DisplayedProducts
    .Where(product.Name.Contains(textToSearch);

// find the most expensive Hammer
Product mostExpensiveHammer = this.DisplayedProducts
    .Where(product.Name.Contains(textToSearch)
    .OrderByDescending(product => product.Price)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**I think that using the DataSource makes it easy to answer your question.**

Because you decoupled your Products from the way it is displayed, it is easy to

- reuse your products for other things
- unit test the products
- change the products, without having to change the ListBox, for instance, you can add a property ProductType, or Location, without having to change the ListBox.
- change the way you have displayed the products without having to change the products. It is easy to add or remove part of the displayed text, without having to change the methods that handle the Products, like searching the products.

So my advice would be to use the DataSource to display the Products in the ListBox

For completeness, the following properties might be handy:

```
Product SelectedProduct => (DisplayedProduct)(this.SelectedValue)?.Product;
```

### Solution if you used ListBox.Items

If you used ListBox.Items to display the Products, your form will have methods like this:

```
// Formats the product into ListBox description, using columns
string ProductToListBoxDescription(Product product)
{
    const string listBoxProductDescriptionFormat = ...;
    return String.Format(listBoxProductDescriptionFormat,
        product.Id,
        product.Name,
        product.Price);
}

void DisplayProductDescriptions(IEnumerable<string> products)
{
    this.myListBox.Items.Clear;
    foreach (Product product in Pro
    this.myListBox.Items.AddRange(products.ToArray());
}
```

To fetch the displayed Products:

```
IEnumerable<string> DisplayedProductDescriptions => this.myListBox.Items.Cast<string>();
```

This disadvantage is, that you have lost the information that the fetched string is a Product. Of course you can just assume that the strings contain Products:

```
const string textToSearch= "Hammer"

string foundHammer = this.DisplayedProductDescriptions
    .Where(description => discription.Contains(textToSearch))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

First of all, your result is still a string. Secondly, what if you try to search for "2.0", for instance if you try to find all Products with version number 2.0? You'll also find Product descriptions that will have a price of €2.0, and €42.0, etc.

So for proper usage, you'll need a method that converts the string back to product

```
Product DescriptionToProduct(string productDescription)
{
    ... // TODO implement. Depends on the columns in your listBox
}
```

Apart from the fact that if you use property Items to display the product descriptions are much bigger than when you use property DataSource, this methods also removes information that the displayed items in the Listbox are Products, which requires extra code to convert the strings back to Products.

So my advice would be: although property Items works, stick to property DataSource.