# How to select LB items

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I populated a `ListBox` with all the courses, so the entries are:

```
Course #1
Course #2
Course #3
Course #4
```

I populated a `DropDownList` with all the column name, so the entries are:

```
Role#1
Role#2
Role#3
```

How can I multi-select items.

Comment: You are struggling here because you are trying to represent a many to many relationship within a single table. You should break this into 3 tables (Courses, Roles and CourseRoles).

Comment: What's wrong with the query in your last sentence?

Comment: I can query the data but how do I select the items in ListBox.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a particular value of the dropdown to be auto-selected, based on what value is returned from the db query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this is what you want:

```
@"SELECT [Course] 
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE [" + dropdownlistID.SelectedItem.Value + "] IS NOT NULL"
```

Comment: How do I match it with the ListBox and auto-select it? Thank you.

Comment: With .net code.   I don't know, I'm a SQL programmer.

Comment: Once you have the ListBox populated with this code you would just set the selected indes of your ListBox (dropdownlistID.SelectedIndex = 0)